# Assign view id to MenuItem programmatically

Tags: android, xml, menuitem

As we are creating our side navigation from a `JSON`, we are creating our `MenuItem`s programmatically.

```
MenuItem currentItem = navigationMenu.add(groupId, R.id.menu_login, order, title);
```

The id is defined in an `XML` resource file.

Calling `currentItem.getItemId()` returns the set id. But using Android Studio's layout inspector shows that for the actual `View` there has **no id** been set. The thing is that we need to have this id for our automated testing framework to access the correct navigation items in the drawer.

Is there any way to set this id to the `View` as it would be set in XML?

Comment: I am facing  same problem like you. Have you got answer?

Comment: Sadly no. I don't think it's possible

Answer (score 1):

When you use a `NavigationView`, and drive your items via a `Menu` (whether by using the xml attribute `app:menu` or by using the `getMenu()` method of the NavigationView), the actual view that the user winds up seeing is a [`NavigationMenuView`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/81fdc55/design/src/android/support/design/internal/NavigationMenuView.java). This is a special subclass of `ListView` that you're not supposed to ever think about (it's in the `internal` package of the library).

The views in this ListView are [`NavigationMenuItemView`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/81fdc55/design/src/android/support/design/internal/NavigationMenuItemView.java)s, and they are created by the [`NavigationMenuAdapter`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/81fdc55/design/src/android/support/design/internal/NavigationMenuPresenter.java#219). They are also something you're never supposed to think about.

All of this is to say that, when you use NavigationView + Menu, there's no way to assign an ID to the views in the layout. Even if you waited for the system to inflate everything and display it, and then tried to manually crawl the view tree and set IDs, you'd still have to contend with the fact that the nav drawer is a ListView and so there's no guarantee that its first child is the first option in the menu.

---

However, there's no need to use NavigationView + Menu for your nav drawer. You *could* instead simply use a `LinearLayout`, and add your own custom views (or maybe just `TextView`s) to it. You're *already* going through the trouble of manually creating `MenuItem`s, so creating a TextView won't be much more difficult.

In this scenario, you're in full control of the view tree, so you can do whatever you want, including setting view IDs.